# I want to connect Arduino UNO to an android app

Tags: android, android-studio, arduino-uno

I want to connect an Arduino UNO to an android mobile app via OTG cable, so that both can connect with each other. Can someone send me the android code for it.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if this is possible, but it's not the easiest way to achieve this. Is more feasible to make an HTTP / Socket ... connection between the application and arduino, having a server in their midst.

App -> Server <- Arduino.